# Passing date to ASMX web service

Tags: c#, android, web-services, asmx, date-parsing

I use asmx web service writes in c# over android device.

I make connection and when in some web method I need integer or string like  input param,all work great, but problem is when web method need date, I try to send date in many format but always I have problem to get answer.

I need to send date object, or like string? It is possible that web service view date like something else?

This is method for "communication" with web service:

```
public void connectSOAP() 
{
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    String dateStr = "04/05/2010"; 
    Date dateObj=null;
    SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mmm/yyyy"); 
    try 
    {
        dateObj = curFormater.parse(dateStr);
    } 
    catch (java.text.ParseException e1) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 
    request.addProperty("dtFrom",dateObj);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    try 
    {
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        if (envelope.getResponse() != null) 
        {
            if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) 
            {
                String str = ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).faultstring;
                Log.i("", str);
            } 
            else 
            {
                SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                Log.d("WS", String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP));
            }    
        };
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Log.d("WS","sss");
    }
}
```

When i change web method(something with out date it work),I get response in log) But when is this way with date i just get catch ("sss" ) in log,i debug and find that it brake on:
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

But i not find anything about that in log except catch that i set...

Comment: What do you mean by "you have a problem getting the answer"? Is it not reading it at all or is it reading it incorrectly? Not a whole lot to go on here unfortunately...

Comment: Thanx for suggestion,I change litle question,added code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this looks like the dateObj which you want to give to the webservice can not be parsed, thats why the exception occurre at this line:

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

But as your formatter has this format:

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mmm/yyyy");
```

Maybe the (three!)"mmm" are causing the error?? I am pretty sure this will produce something like e.g. "Feb" for February and so on.. (e.g. "11/Feb/2014"):

Try something like:

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

or

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Btw, to avoid localisation and interoperability issues, i often use DateTime objects accurately formatted to Strings for giving that objects over to WebService. Because many times i had problems by interoperability between e.g. .asmx Webservice and J2EE web service (e.g. the range of DateTime is not the same for J2EE and .NET and if it's a null/nil value you also run in troubles).

Comment: Thanx for answer, i try many formats(including  yyyy-MM-dd,yyyy-MM-dd, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm , yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm ,yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ etc...) still same problem. All others method without datetime do "job" perfect, but when is web service require date param to don't work. Like that web service want one thing and getting other.. I don't know what to do more..

Comment: You can not switch to string type for that datetime value? Is the web service built by you? You can use a SoapTraceExtension to see what exactly happens on the 'wire' when trying to communicate. I assume you are getting a SoapFault which is saying what is going wrong, but you can see it only when you use a TraceExtension for SOAP messages (there are plenty examples on the web like: http://blog.encoresystems.net/articles/how-to-capture-soap-envelopes-when-consuming-a-web-service.aspx)